# Re-triage posts that were edited while waiting in the Help and Improvement queue

Tags: feature-request, edits, triage, help-improvement

The first thing I used to do when reviewing in the [Help and Improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper)
queue is to spot what caused the [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage)rs to select these items as needing H&I. Only then would I read through the whole post systematically and apply changes, being sure not to miss, what I think, was the cause for the post to end up in the queue.

Now that H&I is gaining some backlog, I often get posts a day or two old, and that increases the chance of such post having been edited in the mean time (outside of the review process, or maybe through some other queue than H&I or Triage). For those posts it is more likely than for non-edited posts, that they no longer need further H&I.

Could these posts be re-inserted into the Triage queue after such edits, so they might not show up in the H&I if re-triaged as OK?¹ Currently I press the Skip button, but I am not sure how long or how many Skips it takes for a post to move out of the H&I queue without further edit.

I was originally thinking about no longer offering a post for H&I if edited by a user with high enough reputation, but I have come across such edits where only part of the issues were addressed and that clearly needed further improvement.

An alternative would be to have a "No longer needs H&I" button, but that would essentially mean a one-person re-triage without the post getting back in the Triage queue.

---

¹ <sub>I certainly hope this is not already in process, because that would mean I am getting quite a few reviews that are IMO incorrectly triaged.</sub>

Comment: Things being incorrectly triaged? No, I'm sorry, that is simply unimaginable.

Comment: @TZHX Yes, I know, it sounds absurd. I will double check, they are probably my own Triage reviews that I am referring to. Can't imagine anyone else making mistakes.